# Subdomain and Googlebot can't access your site

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot

I have a subdomain and Google Webmaster Tools, told me this:

> Googlebot can't access your site

This is not the first time that I receive this message from Google's Webmaster Tools.

I need to should I contact my hosting company technical support? In other words, is it a problem related with the server?!

Also I noticed a great decrease of traffic to my website after receiving this message from the first time. I have set many subdomains on my web host, and some of them is not exist, i.e. its directory is deleted.

The following is a copy of the message from Google's Webmaster Tools:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of possibilities why Googlebot cannot access your site. Some of them are:

- Your hosting is down and Googlebot happened to crawl during this time
- Your website is giving the error 500 Internal Server Error (this can be caused by loop in *.htaccess*, or by infinite loop script from your website)

If you are sure that your website (script & *.htaccess*) is not faulty, then most likely the problem lies in your hosting provider.

I would recommend contacting the technical support since you have nothing to lose by contacting them.

Comment: I contacted the technical support and they told me that there are slow mysql queries that leads to CPU Throttling. Now I try to find out a solution for this CPU Throttling. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583347/slow-mysql-query-and-cpu-throttling